# Haskell: Type Error in Explicitly Typed Binding

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create a function that will remove all occurrences of a given character in a string, but being the Haskell amateur that I am, I've run into issues that are making it hard to sleep.

Here's my code:

```
remove:: Char -> String -> Int
remove[] = []
remove (char : list) = char : remove (filter (\elm -> not (char == elm) ) list)
```

With the type definitions in, I get the following error code:

```
ERROR "a5.hs":17 - Type error in explicitly typed binding
*** Term           : char : list
*** Type           : [a]
*** Does not match : Char
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: `remove = filter . (/=)`

Answer (score 1):

The type signature says that `remove` takes two parameters, a `Char` and a `String`, and gives back an `Int`.

The error message refers to the second equation, which tries to match the first parameter (a `Char`) to `(char : list)` (a list).

Perhaps you meant

```
remove char list = ...
```

?

Further errors:

1. The first equation makes the same mistake (trying to match an empty list with the `Char` parameter).

   Perhaps this should be

   ```
   remove _ [] = ...
   ```

   (`_` means to match anything.)
2. The type signature says that the result is an `Int`, but your equations give a `String` result.

There are more mistakes. But that will get you started.

---

**Edit:** In response to your first comment:

1. The type signature should be

   ```
   remove :: Char -> String -> String
   ```

   `remove` takes a `Char` and a `String` and gives back a `String`.

   When you put `remove :: Char -> String`, that means `remove` takes a `Char` and gives back a `String`.
2. `(\elm -> flip (==) elm)`

   is the same as `(\elm -> (==) elm)`

   is the same as `(\elm birch -> (==) elm birch)`

   is the same as `(\elm birch -> elm == birch)`

   is also the same as `(==)`.

   This expression has the type `a -> a -> Bool`, but you are passing it as the first parameter to `filter`, which expects a function with type `a -> Bool` (i.e. it wants a function that takes one parameter, not a function that takes two).

   (This is what the error message is telling you about.)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I've edited now to look like this:
    `"remove:: Char -> String
    remove char list = char : remove (filter (\elm -> (==elm) ) list)"`

Thanks for clearing that up regarding the : business. But now I've got a new error because of my changes!
Type error in application
`*** Expression     : filter (\elm -> flip (==) elm) list
*** Term           : \elm -> flip (==) elm
*** Type           : a -> a -> Bool
*** Does not match : Char -> Bool`

Any more words of wisdom? (Also if you know how I can format a comment better, that'd be very helpful.)

Comment: @SamOfloinn You can't format a comment better: either edit your question to include your new code and new error at the end, or ask a new question. But see the edit I'm about to make to my answer.